# how to build and compile Angular8 source code

Tags: angular

Download Angular8 source code from https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/8.1.x.
Try to build the Angular8 source code locally with “ yarn run bazel build“ but it doesn’t output any bundle results.

Does anyone know how to build/compile Angular8 source locally?

Comment: Why would you want to do this ?